# kdb+/q table - convert string to number

Tags: kdb

assume you have a table

```
tbl:([] id:("123"; ""; "invalid"))
```

And want to parse this string into a number.

Invalid values - in the example above, both the empty string "" as well as the value "invalid", should be parsed to null (0Nj).

How can you best do it? My initial approach was

```
select id:.[value;;0Nj] each enlist each id from tbl
```

But while that will parse the both the "123" as well as "invalid" entries correctly, it will return the unary operator :: instead of null when trying to parse the row with the empty string.

Of course I could do something like

```
select id:.[value;;0Nj] each enlist each id from update id:string (count id)#`invalid from tbl where id like ""
```

but this seems kind of.. ugly/inefficient. Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"J"$` to cast the column

```
q)select "J"$id from tbl
id
---
123
```

https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/tok/

Comment: Jesus! The lengths I went through when it could have been that simple. Thanks, that works

Comment: No problem - added link to kx documentation

Answer (score 1):

how about just cast it to long?

```
q)update id:"J"$id from `tbl
`tbl
q)select from tbl where not null id
id
---
123
```